# asp.net website problem

Tags: asp.net

I have my asp .net website. I have uploaded that. But is shows code of default.aspx page and not the design.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: What version of IIS? Is the correct .net version installed on the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS will by default display the page `default.aspx`.

You can change this in your IIS settings and change it to pick up another file by default (though it will allow multiple names).

Alternatively, change the filename of your default page to default.aspx.

Other possibilities:

- The .NET framework is not installed on the server
- The .NET framework is not registered on IIS (in the framework directory run `aspnet_regiis`)

Comment: Sounds to me like it's serving default.aspx as text rather than as dynamic content.

Comment: The question is not clear enough to speculate on that... You might be right, why not post an answer to that?

Comment: Thanks.
actually I have linux hosting, i think the problem is because of that only.
can I do asp on linux hosting??

Comment: You can. Lookup apache and mod_mono.